# New to C++, coding syntax

Tags: c++

Can use help with this code I am writing in my free time. I am a beginner to C++. The things I am seeking help with:

-Need help with proper loop, especially if user input is not an integer, but characters
-When I try to compile, there shows an error with the case statements, and it points to the parenthesis, I don't know why.

The code is supposed to solve for certain variables with kinematic equations learned from Physics class. It is a way for me to get used to the beginning of C++ but could use some help from advanced coders.

This is also my first time posting on stackoverflow, if anybody has some tips on posting properly let me know, will check for any responses after my programming class is done, will also ask my professor.

```
//Arthur Byra
//27 January 2015
//Program to calculate kinetic equations


/* 
vf = vi + a(t)
x = vi(t) + 1/2(a)(t)^2
vf^2 = vi^2 +2a(s) 

where:

    vi + initial velocity
    vf = final velocity
    s = distance
    a = acceleration (must be constant)
    t = time in seconds
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int userInput = 0;
    double initialVelocity = 0;
    double finalVelocity = 0;
    double acceleration = 0;
    double time = 0;
    double deltaDistance = 0;
    char userInputSolveFor;

    cout << "This is a program to calculate certain variables using kinematic equations." << endl;
    cout << "Remember that kinematic equations only work when acceleration is constant!" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Which equation did you want to use?" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1) vf = vi + a(t)" << endl;
    cout << "2) x = vi(t) + 1/2(a)(t)^2" << endl;
    cout << "3) vf^2 = vi^2 + 2(a)(x)" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Input number of the equation you want to use (1,2,3): " << endl;
    cin >> userInput;
    switch (userInput)
    {
        case (userInput == 1):

            cout << "You are using vf = vi + a(t)." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "What are you trying to solve for?" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Use a for acceleration (in m/s/s)." << endl;
            cout << "Use vi for initial velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
            cout << "Use vf for final velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
            cout << "Use t for time (in seconds)." << endl;
            cin >> userInputSolveFor;
            cout << endl;
            switch (userInputSolveFor)
            {
                case (userInputSolveFor == a):

                    cout << "You are solving for acceleration." << endl; //Solving for acceleration
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the final velocity (in m/s)?" endl;
                    cin >> finalVelocity;
                    cout >> "What is the time (in seconds)?" << endl;
                    cin >> time;
                    cout << "The acceleration is " << (finalVelocity - initialVelocity) / time << setprecision(10) << " m/s/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == vi):

                    cout << "You are solving for initial velocity." << endl; //Solving for initial velocity
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is your acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is your final velocity (in m/s)?" endl;
                    cin >> finalVelocity;
                    cout >> "What is the time (in seconds)?" << endl;
                    cin >> time;
                    cout << "The initial velocity is " << finalVelocity / (acceleration * time) << setprecision(10) << " m/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == vf):

                    cout << "You are solving for final velocity." << endl; //Solving for final velocity
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is your acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is your initial velocity (in m/s)?" endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout >> "What is the time (in seconds)?" << endl;
                    cin >> time;
                    cout << "The final velocity is " << initialVelocity + (acceleration * time) << setprecision(10) << " m/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == t):

                    cout << "You are solving for time." << endl; //Solving for time
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity (in m/s)?" endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout >> "What is the final velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> finalVelocity;
                    cout << "The time is " << (finalVelocity - initialVelocity) / acceleration << setprecision(10) << " seconds." << endl;
                break;

                default:

                    cout <<"The input you have entered is not valid." << endl;
        break;
            }

        case (userInput == 2):

            cout << "You are using x = vi(t) + 1/2(a)(t)^2." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "What are you trying to solve for?" <<endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Use x for distance (in meters)." << endl;
            cout << "Use vi for initial velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
            cout << "Use t for time (in seconds)." << endl;
            cout << "Use a for acceleration (in m/s/s)." <<endl;
            cin >> userInputSolveFor;
            cout << endl;
            switch (userInputSolveFor)
            {
                case (userInputSolveFor == a):
                    cout << "You are solving for acceleration." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
                    cin >> deltaDistance;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the time (in seconds)?" << endl;
                    cin >> time;
                    cout << "The acceleration is " << deltaDistance - (initialVelocity * time) / (0.5 * pow(time, 2.0)) << setprecision(10) << " m/s/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == vi):

                    cout << "You are solving for initial velocity." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
                    cin >> deltaDistance;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is the time (in seconds)?" << endl;
                    cin >> time;
                    cout << "The initial velocity is " << (deltaDistance - ((pow(time, 2.0)) * acceleration * 0.5)) / time << setprecision(10) << " m/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == x):

                    cout << "You are solving for distance." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the time (in seconds)?" << endl;
                    cin >> time;
                    cout << "The distance is " << (initialVelocity * time) + ((pow(time, 2.0)) * acceleration * 0.5) << setprecision(10) << " meters." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == t):

                    cout << "You are solving for time." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
                    cin >> deltaDistance;

                    if (initialVelocity == 0):
                    {
                        cout << "The time is " << sqrt(deltaDistance - (0.5 * acceleration)) << setprecision(10) << " seconds." << endl;
                    }
                    else if (acceleration == 0):
                    {
                        cout << "The time is " << (deltaDistance / initialVelocity) << setprecision(10) << " seconds." << endl;
                    }

                break;

                default:
                    cout <<"The input you have entered is not valid." << endl;

        break;
            }

        case (userInput == 3):

            cout << "You are using vf^2 = vi^2 + 2(a)(x)." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "What are you trying to solve for?" <<endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "Use vf for final velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
            cout << "Use vi for initial velocity (in m/s)." << endl;
            cout << "Use a for acceleration." << endl;
            cout << "Use x for distance (in meters)." <<endl;
            cin >> userInputSolveFor;
            cout << endl;
            switch (userInputSolveFor)
            {
                case (userInputSolveFor == vf):

                    cout << "You are solving for final velocity." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
                    cin >> deltaDistance;
                    cout << "The final velocity is " << (sqrt(pow(initialVelocity, 2.0))) + (2 * acceleration * deltaDistance) << setprecision(10) << " m/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == vi):

                    cout << "You are solving for initial velocity." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the final velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> finalVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
                    cin >> deltaDistance;
                    cout << "The initial velocity is " << (sqrt(pow(finalVelocity, 2.0)) / (2 * acceleration * deltaDistance) << setprecision(10) << " m/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == a):

                    cout << "You are solving for acceleration." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the final velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> finalVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the distance (in meters)?" << endl;
                    cin >> deltaDistance;
                    cout << "The acceleration is " << (sqrt(pow(finalVelocity, 2.0)) - (sqrt(pow(initialVelocity, 2.0)))) / (2 * deltaDistance)) << setprecision(10) << " m/s/s." << endl;
                break;

                case (userInputSolveFor == x):

                    cout << "You are solving for distance." << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                    cout << "What is the final velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> finalVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the initial velocity (in m/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> initialVelocity;
                    cout << "What is the acceleration (in m/s/s)?" << endl;
                    cin >> acceleration;
                    cout << "The distance is " << (sqrt(pow(finalVelocity, 2.0)) - sqrt(pow(initialVelocity, 2.0))) / (2.0 * acceleration) << setprecision(10) << " meters." << endl;
                break;

                default:
                    cout <<"The input you have entered is not valid." << endl;
        break;
            }

    default:
        while (userInput <= 1 || userInput >= 3)
        {
        cout << "The number you have entered is not valid." << endl;
        cin >> userInput;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should just be `case 1:` instead of `case (userInput == 1)`

Comment: Any time you get “there shows an error” you need to tell us the error.

Comment: Please check every input: `if(cin >> userInput) { ... } else { /* error */ }`

Comment: Tips on posting properly, you say? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for better questions: you need to post a [**mcve**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) As it is you have tens of lines of code that are irrelevant to your error. Another **must do** is post the actual error message as well as a commentary in the code to indicate where the error appears (we don't have line numbers in the code here)

Comment: Programming tip: Compile often, especially when you're unsure about syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `case (userInput == 1):`

You cannot do such using a `switch()/case:` control structure.
Also a single char cannot take input like `vi` or `vf`, you need to use a `std::string userInput;` instead.

What you actually need is a cascading `if()/else if()/else` control structure, something like this:

```
if (userInputSolveFor == "a") {                 
    cout << "You are solving for acceleration." << endl;
    // ...
}
else if (userInputSolveFor == "vi") {
    cout << "You are solving for initial velocity." << endl;
    // ...
}
else if(userInputSolveFor == "vf") {
    cout << "You are solving for final velocity." << endl;
    // ...
}
// a.s.o
else { // <<< That's equivalent to default:
    cout <<"The input you have entered is not valid." << endl;
}
```

Regarding checking proper numerical input, do like Dieter Lücking proposed in his comment:

```
if(cin >> userInput) {
   // ... 
} 
else { 
    /* error */ 
}
```

That will need to have an `int` type variable for `userInput`, so probably you want to use a different variable for your *main menu selections* (for the equation).

Comment: I have changed the formal of the code to include if and else if statements instead of case and break statements, and have also made the post mcve (hopefully). Don't know if it is possible to unhold this thread but hopefully I can get somebody to help me with these last bit of errors

Comment: @ArtByra That edit of your question, made this answer worthless now. Anyway, as far I can spot (and the compiler error tells you), you are simply missing some closing braces `}`.

Comment: How did I make your answer worthless? I changed the format of the code to what you suggested in the first place

Comment: @ArtByra Such that no one can see now what the original problem was.

Comment: Would you want me to revert the edits? -- Also I have fixed the first error, I was missing a closing brace, but the other error persists.

Comment: @ArtByra Yes, I think reverting the edits, and post the other errors as a new question would be more helpful for future researchers, hitting the same problem.